# Flutter Multiline for text

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

All I need is my text to be multi-line. Am giving the property of `maxLines` but its still getting `RenderFlex` overflowed error to the right as the next is not going to 2nd line,

```
      Align( alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: new ButtonBar(
        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: new Text(
              "This is a very bigggggggg text !!!",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I have fixed by removing the ButtonBar child

Comment: Wrap your Text Widget in a Flexible or Expanded Widget.

Answer (score 133):

***Short answer***

All that is required for multi-line text, is that your `Text()` widgets' width is limited by a parent widget. For example:

```dart
SizedBox(
    width: 150,
    child: Text(
    "This text is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long",
    ),
),
```

***Long answer***

Minimal working example + explanation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold( //Text widgets, multi-line or not, need a Scaffold widget somewhere up the widget tree.
        body: Row( //Widgets which help to display a list of children widgets are the 'culprit', they make your text widget not know what the maximum width is. In OP's example it is the ButtonBar widget.
          children: [
            Container( 
              width: 100, //This helps the text widget know what the maximum width is again! You may also opt to use an Expanded widget instead of a Container widget, if you want to use all remaining space.
              child: Center( //I added this widget to show that the width limiting widget doesn't need to be a direct parent.
                child: Text(
                  "This text is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Extra***

You also mentioned `maxlines`. This property limits the
maximum amount of lines. If this is what you want, I recommend you also play with the `overflow` property.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  child: Text(
    "This text is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long",
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
),
```

***UPDATE***

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVki2CIzBTs) on the official Flutter channel which explains this issue quite well. They recommend using a *LimitedBox* widget.

Comment: This explanation is so good: precise, concise, correct. I wish we had official Flutter docs (guides / how-to's) written in this style.

Comment: If I use TextOverFlow.ellipsis and wrap the Text widget with a SingleChildScrollView, the text doesn't scroll. But if I remove the TextOverFlow.ellipsis the text scroll as expected. Is it possible to use TextOverFlow.ellipsis and SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: Better approach to use constraints  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431670/7429464

Comment: What to do when `Text` is inside `Wrap` widget? Nothing seems to work in this case and text goes in single long line causing overflow

Answer (score 48):

Just wrap your text widget with Expanded as below

```
    Expanded(
      child: Text('data', maxLines: 4,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,),
    ),
```

Comment: I already voted it up, then I forgot how to do it and found this answer again. I can't vote up again so I decided to write a comment (maybe like this I will remember better ) Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

try this:

```
Expanded(            
    child: Text(
      'a long text',
      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
    ),
),
```

in my implementation I put this inside a row and surrounded it with sized boxes on each side so that I have some space between my elements, why using expanded you may ask, well it's used to take as much space as possible so the text would look good in portrait or landscape mode.

and here is a full example on how to make it even react vertically not just horizontally:

```
Card(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){},
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 70, // default\minimum height
          ),
          Container(
            height: 44,
            width: 44,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(22))),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'the very long title',
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            'value', //some other text in the end of the card or maybe an icon instead
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you forgot to add `overflow` type.

You can use something like this:

```
Text(
     "TOP ADDED",
     textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
     maxLines: 2,)
```

Comment: textAlign setting ensured centering for multiple lines, separated with "\n" character.  e.g.  Text("line one\nlinetwo", textAlign:  TextAlign.center)

Answer (score 11):

Use Expanded widget with column to achieve multiline text.

```
Expanded(child: 
 Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start ,
 children: [
            Text(food.title),
            Text(food.price)
           ]
))
```

Answer (score 9):

Just wrap the text widget in Flexible. As it only use space that it need.
After maxLines, it just cut to ellipsis.

> If you want unlimited lines, just remove `maxLines` attribute. With the help of Flexible, it uses space which widget needs.

```
Flexible(
  child: Text('Long Text', maxLines: 3,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this trick.
`Text( ''' This is very big text''' )`,
Just wrap a text around three single quotes and flutter will format a text as per its length . No need to use max lines and text field.

Comment: works, as long as you add `\n` as line breaks in your string. Doesn't matter if you use tripple or normal quotes though. Can't understand all of the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to handle this:

```
Expanded(
child: Text(document['content'],
textAlign: TextAlign.start,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
maxLines: 20,
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `TextField`:

```
new TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your Text widget with AutoSizeText widget and also Flexible widget.

- AutoSizeText adjust your text size as per the screen size
- Flexible control your widget not to overflow outside

  for get AutoSizeText you have to add dependency.
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0 - Example

Answer (score 1):

**Maxline is used for set how many lines you want to set or see.**

```
Text(
     "Name Safal Bhatia",
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
     maxLines: 3,)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Text.rich` to show your text in multi line or mansge the style for subTitle in your whole title.

This example will help  you to understand what I mean:

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'world',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: '!',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)


----------

        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "set your paragraph here"
              ),
              const TextSpan(
                text: ("More....."),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
```