# Limit max width of Container in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout, word-wrap, flutter-container

```
  Widget build(context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 300,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: color ?? Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
          child: msg
        )
      ],  
    );
  }
```

This is build method of my widget and It renders this UI depending on what I pass as `msg` paramter

1. Loading text
   [image]
2. Some very long text
   [image]

Now the issue I am facing is that I am not able to wrap the text inside this container/blue box without setting it's width but If I set width of container/blue box then it will always stay that wide no matter how short the text is.

Now is there a way to set maxWidth (like let's say 500) of container/blue box? So that the blue box will become as wide as required for small text like "Loading" and for long text it will expand till it reaches width of 500 units and then will wrap the text ?

**Required output for long text:**

For small text like loading I dont want any change in UI but for long text I want it to look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 222):

You can add a constraint to the Container Widget with the preferred `maxWidth` like this:

```
Widget build(context) {
return Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color ?? Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
      ),
      child: msg
    )
  ],  
);
}
```

Answer (score 51):

Use `ConstrainedBox` with `BoxConstraints` `maxWidth`, wrapped in a `Flexible()` widget. The Flexible widget allows for the box to resize for smaller screens as well.

```
Flexible(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
    child: Container(
      color : Colors.blue,
      child: Text('Your Text here'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I just tried it, and the problem is that it overflows the screen in case the screen is not that large.

Comment: Fixed! Just put this ConstrainerBox inside a Flexible :·)

Comment: in some cases e.g. when the `ConstrainedBox` is inside a row with multiple expanded elements, the `Flexible` solution wont work. what I did is doing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 150` check and return the widget without a `ConstrainedBox` if so

Answer (score 16):

This required to be inside `Row` or `Column` Widget

**1. Row**

```
  Row(
      children: [
        Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
            child: Text("Long Text....")
        ),
      ],
    );
```

**2. Column**

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
            child: Text("Long Text....")
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Here in both examples, it's working because `Column` and `Row` allow it's children to expand to it's given constraint/size.

**Note:** If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size might be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple method I use for long texts:

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
  child: Container(
    child: Text(
      'Long string of text',
      maxLines: 2,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Note the `maxLines` attribute which might be helpful should you wish to show just a single line of text.

Answer (score 7):

For me at least putting the Constrained box in IntrinsicWidth has solved issue.

```
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
    child: Row(
      children: [
       
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Is recommend by Flutter, avoid use IntrinsicWidth and IntrinsicHeight when posible, because is too expensive to build

Comment: Great suggestion.
It allows for aligning components without making the container fill max size

Answer (score 4):

Use `Constraints` property in `Container` widget.

use `maxWidth` & `minWidth` value to achieve the requirement.

```
 Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 300),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child: Text("")
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how i fixed it

```
Center(
    child: Container(
      child: this.child,
      width: 300,
      height: double.infinity,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a Flexible around the text and then wrap the Flexible in a fixed size containter? Just an idea.

Comment: I don't want to give fixed size to the container because container is the one which is providing the blue background and if I give it a fixed size then even when I show "Loading" message the blue container will not shrink to adapt to short text.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but someone may get help in the future.
I used the *auto_size_text plugin* to get it done:

```
AutoSizeText(
  'A really long String',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  minFontSize: 18,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case my solution was this:
Wrapped in Row and add Spacer (in comment bubble widget I didn't define either width any max-width. it grows depends on the text.
to limit width added padding to comment bubble.

```
return Row(
      children: [
          CommentBubble(
              chatText: snapshot.get('text'),
              sentAt: snapshot.get('sentAt'),
              sendBy: snapshot.get('sendBy'),
          ),
          Spacer(),
      ],
);
```