# How can I center a content container in Flutter like a "max-width" container in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flutter

##### How would one make a centered content container like this in Flutter?:

[image]
[image]

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Hello inside container
</div>
```

---

I have tried this, but it just overflows instead of fitting to the width of the screen once the application is smaller than the maxWidth.

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "Hello inside container",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code wrap your `Column` inside [**`Expanded`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [**`Flexible`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.red,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Text(
                "Hello inside container",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Didn't work with `Expanded`, but it worked with `Flexible`. 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` as width. It gives you the full width of screen. Also [Limit max width of Container in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185288/limit-max-width-of-container-in-flutter) have a look at this.