# multiline text in row

Tags: flutter, dart, text

[image: multiline text in row]

as you can see I have an Icon at start of each text but the text can be multiline.
the problem is that in row , it will be overflow and I can't create such this text.

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Multiline for text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811932/flutter-multiline-for-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping your `Text` with a `Flexible` Widget.

Try the code below: It works perfectly:

```
Flexible(
child: Text(
      'Your text here'
      ),
    ),
```

I hope this helps.